# Should I be using Core Data if I only want one record for an Entity

Tags: core-data

I am new with Core Data and wanted to know if I should use it or not.  I want an entity to only have one record which has a bunch of attributes.  Should I be using something else or is Core Data fine for this?

For example:  I have a user's home entity and it has a bunch of attributes about the house, but I expect the user to have only one home.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should make your model class to be NSCoding compliant and store it on NSUserDefaults. Using core data to store only one record brings the overhead of the core data stack, and it's a hefty price for only 1 record.